# .ndf file location in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server-2014

Is there a way to find the location of `.ndf` file in SQL Server 2014?

I have checked the directory from this path:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\
```

Comment: When you're connected to that database, use `SELECT * FROM sys.database_files` and you'll get all info - include the `physical name` which is the path and file name of your database file

Comment: Or with Management Studio, right click your database, `Properties` then `Files` then scroll to the right and look at `Path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will show you all the files for all the databases on the server:

```
SELECT  DB_NAME(database_id) AS [db_name] ,
        type_desc AS [file_type] ,
        name AS [logical_filename] ,
        physical_name AS [file_path]
FROM    sys.master_files;
```

You can filter this by looking for .ndf extensions if you wish.